# Is there any Oracle Driver (module) for Drupal 9?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-9, drupal-database

The Oracle Driver works with Drupal 8, but its composer installation doesn’t work with Drupal 9.
https://www.drupal.org/project/oracle

**My goal is to use the Views Database Connector module to interact with the external Oracle Database.**
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_database_connector
That’s why I’m looking for the Oracle driver.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Regards,

Leandro

Answer (score 0):

[A patch for a new version 3.x of Drupal's Oracle Driver](https://www.drupal.org/project/oracle/issues/3245880) has recently been proposed for merge. Perhaps this is what you are looking for? It claims compatibility up to Drupal 9.2, but requires Oracle 19c or above.